# Using Single Iteration Circular References in Excel

Tags: excel, circular-reference

Circular References in Excel are enabled by setting "Enable Iterative Calculation" at "Options/Formulas". A "Maximum Iterations" value of 1 could be an interesting choice, but there are still problems.

At some moments, I am in the urge to replace a wrong value in a specific cell `CELL` in a `COLUMN` with the value `=1-TOTALS` where `TOTALS` is the cell holding the result of several sheets, like `=SUM(COLUMN)`.

Normally, I have Excel (>2013) worksheets within a structure where all columns sum the same quantity, e.g. 1000 values completing 100% with data from different datasets. Assume you want to stick with Circular Referentes, by not changing the workbook structure, of by calling a macro, or by calling the Solver each time.

I always end typing manually, tediously, repetitively, the proper value at `CELL` when that happens.

**Problem**

The Circular Reference adds a constant to the linked cells, and I don't find a clear way to "tie" any of the values to a given constant reference (in this case, easily, the final sum shall always be 1). If the maximum iteration is 1, it calculates correctly, but when calculating a second time, the drift starts.

**Question**

Is there some way to use a *Circular Reference* formula in `CELL`, allowing the *Circular Reference* to exist, enabling *Iterative Calculations* with a *Maximum Iteration* of 1, and most importantly, in some way fixing the 100% result at the end of the column, so the iteration do not drift?.

Comment: Can't you place the formula in that specific cell? Please keep in mind that you want the value of that cell to be 1 minus the sum of everything in that column *except* that specific cell ... So theoretically you should not need a circular reference.

Comment: Interesting problem. I came up with an actual formula that wasn't circular (using `INDIRECT()` and `ADDRESS()`, but unfortunately excel thought it was circular ...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a circular formula.

I would start by making a Name: `LAST_ROW`, and fill it with the appropriate (probably 1048576) number for the version of excel in which that worksheet was made.

And then you can simply use a formula. For instance, for cell `K10` it would be:

```
=1 - SUM(OFFSET(K10,1-ROW(),0,ROW()-1,1)) - SUM(OFFSET(K10, 1, 0, LAST_ROW-ROW(), 1))
```

---

Explanation:

`SUM(OFFSET(<this cell>,1-ROW(),0,ROW()-1,1))` gives the sum of everything above this cell
`SUM(OFFSET(<this cell>, 1, 0, LAST_ROW-ROW(), 1))` gives the sum of everything below this cell.